# How to move a sprite in a straight line in XNA?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I'm making a whack the mole like game where 4 enemies come from all 4 directions:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2861523/dskjds.png]

I've got the 4 enemy sprites and all I want them to do is walk accross the x or y axis towards the cow in the centre. When the direction key is clicked they get reset to their orginal position. E.g. If the farmer on the left went towards the cow in the centre you would click left to send him back.

Comment: Please post some info regarding what you've done, how and why do you think it might work badly, i.e. which module? Check your click events for bogus forgotten about pieces of code (esp. positioning)

Comment: I have the assets loaded in. Thats about it.

Comment: My cow spins around when I click the direction keys as well, but nothing relevent. I've spent a few hours looking into this and couldn't find much. Kinda need to do this for tomorrow so I figured I'd ask people who actually know what they're doing.

Comment: Considering that you're already drawing the sprites at a position, it should be pretty simple to simply change that position.

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty much asking us to program the entire gameplay logic for you. You should tackle one problem at a time, and post a question for *one* specific problem. I'm just going to answer the question on your title (*How to move a sprite in a straight line*) since that's the more concrete problem.

First define variables for the `position`, `direction` (which should be normalized) and `speed` of your sprite. You probably already have the position since you're drawing the sprite on screen.

```
Vector2 position;       // Position of the sprite, where it is drawn
Vector2 direction;      // Normalized vector pointing in the direction to move
float speed;            // Speed in units (pixels if not zooming) per second
```

Having these three, you can make the sprite move the in the specified direction by doing the following in the `Update` method:

```
float dt = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
position += direction * speed * dt;
```

For example, to make the sprite move left to right you'd do something like:

```
direction = new Vector2(1,0);     // Points right
speed = 100f;                     // Moves 100 pixels per second
```

Comment: Why is `dt` using `TotalSeconds` instead of seconds since last tick?

Comment: @ashes999 `dt` *is* the amount of seconds since the *previous* frame. `TotalSeconds` is just a property of the `TimeSpan` structure that returns the amount of seconds in that timespan as a floating point number. The important part is that I'm calling it on `ElapsedGameTime`, and you're probably confusing it with `TotalGameTime`.